# Reason for MINOR vs PATCH rules in SemVer

Tags: semantic-versioning

The rules for when to increase the MAJOR vs the MINOR version number with [SemVer 2.0](http://semver.org/spec/v2.0.0.html) are very compelling.  They clearly give a lot of advantages to knowing if the app/service is backwards compatible.

But the site does not really give an reason for the differences between a MINOR and what it calls a PATCH. I don't see it giving the same benefits of MAJOR vs MINOR.

For reference here are the SemVer rules:

1. MAJOR version when you make incompatible API changes,
2. MINOR version when you add functionality in a backwards-compatible manner, and
3. PATCH version when you make backwards-compatible bug fixes.

So the only difference between MINOR and PATCH is features vs bug fixes.  My company wants to do that differently.

They want to have MINOR be a collection of [backwards compatible] features.  "PATCH" (which we call Incremental) be the releases needed to get those features out.  (We release bug fixes as we release features.)

For example, if we plan for 7 [backwards compatible] features in our 2.4 release then 2.4.0 may have 2 of the features, 2.4.1 would have 3 more features and 2.4.2 would have the last 2 (perhaps with a bug fix or two in each release).

I can see that this violates SemVer, but I need to know **why SemVer has decided to be prescriptive on the differences between the MINOR and PATCH versions** so I can know which way to push my company.

*NOTE: I hope that this is not too subjective for Stack Overflow.  I don't usually ask questions like this, so it is possible that this question will need to be closed...*

Comment: This might be a better question for https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Blorgbeard when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Answer (score 21):

The standard is deliberately terse. There's nothing in it that prevents you from releasing a bunch of bug fixes along with your new features and you only have to bump the minor field when you do this. If the changes only involve bug fixes, refactoring or documentation that does not add, remove or modify any interface, then you only bump the patch.  The whole point is to communicate to your consumers, their level of risk when taking an update from you.

EDIT:
It is a best practice to separate bug fixes (patches) from feature work (minor) and breaking changes (major), into separate releases. This allows your consumers to automatically pick up the latest fixes, without having to deal with feature bloat or breaking changes.

Answer (score 1):

> For example, if we plan for 7 [backwards compatible] features in our 2.4 release then 2.4.0 may have 2 of the features, 2.4.1 would have 3 more features and 2.4.2 would have the last 2 (perhaps with a bug fix or two in each release).

Nothing stops you following SemVer convention and release 2.4.0 with 2 features, 2.5.0 with 3 more features and 2.6.0 with last 2 features and a few bug fixes for previously released features.

It is better to follow some common convention instead of reinventing the wheel. You save time thinking, discussing and documenting a custom solution as well as avoid confusion within the team and newcomers.

https://semver.org/